# Writing data on a Kafka compacted topic - how to set the record key

Tags: apache-kafka, key, record, spring-cloud-dataflow

Using spring cloud dataflow, I'm trying to replicate data from a database using a Kafka compacted topic. For this reason I need to set the key of the record while producing records into the topic (called foo).

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --create --topic foo --replication-factor=1 --partitions 3 --config cleanup.policy=compact 



stream create --name foo --deploy --definition "jdbc --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/chiodonia --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver --jdbc.max-rows-per-poll=10 --jdbc.query='select id, value from foo where seen is null' --jdbc.split=true --jdbc.update='update foo set seen=current_timestamp where id in (:id)' --trigger.fixed-delay=5 --trigger.time-unit=SECONDS | header-enricher --headers='recordkey=payload.id' > :foo --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.messageKeyExpression=headers['recordkey']"
```

Anyone able to set the key of records into kafka using spring cloud dataflow?

Answer (score 0):

To override the binding config for the output channel, you'd have to set it to the channel going outward from `header-enricher` processor to the `foo` topic.

That'd be:

> stream create --name foo --deploy --definition "jdbc ...... | header-enricher --headers='recordkey=payload.id' --spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.output.producer.messageKeyExpression=headers['recordkey'] > :foo"